# Is there a way to send to all connections in the python 3.8 socket module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I haven't found a way to send to all connections connected with the [Socket Module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html).

Ive already tried making a function to send to all, but it doesn't send yet it returns fine. The function is shown below.

This is for a game i am making and i have a list of players named Players. The players in the list are all objects and have an attribute that is a connection. When i am using the default send method it sends fine, but when i use this it doesn't send at all.

The send function is a custom function and it looks like this:

```py
def Send(C, Message):
    try:
        P = Process(target=C.send, args=(f"{Message}".encode(), ))
        P.start() #Start the process
        P.join() #Wait to finish
        return 0
    except Exception as e:
        if PrintErrors:
            print(f"ConnectionError: {e.__class__.__name__}")
```

```py
def SendToAll(Message):
    if Message:
        Message = "`GameOver` "
    i = 0
    while i < len(Players):
        Send(Players[i].C, f"{Message}`n` ")
        i = i + 1
```

I want this to send to all connections that are stored, but it sends to none.

I am yet to find anything on this problem so any help would be great!

Comment: Why using a `Process`? What is `Players.C`?

Comment: @Daniel Players[i].C is the connection that was assigned to the player. it comes from the Socket.accept() function. (returns C and Address) then with that you can do C.send(Message) but i have a custom function to do that. I am using processes because that is a way to keep multiple connections open at the same time. if you want it the github repo is https://github.com/Kat9274/Uno

Comment: Note that names that start with a capital letter should be used for *classes*, not *instances*. Thus, `Players` should instead be named `players` if (as sensible) it's an *instance* of a class; see PEP-8 for Python's naming conventions to avoid confusing your readers.